# can't access api using angular

Tags: angular, api, api-authorization

I have an API, which I need to consume to create reports, However that API requires username and password to access it, by using curl command I can access the API

```
curl -X GET "https://SomeApiCall/api/v1/customers/" -H "accept:application/json; charset=UTF-8" -u "username:password"
```

but when I am trying to use same API using angular I am getting below error

```
key:"api.error.invalid_auth_schema"
message: "Invalid authentication scheme is used. Only Basic Authentication scheme is supported (login and password should be provided)"
```

Angular sample code:

```
 this.data = this.http.get("https://SomeApiCall/api/v1/customers/" , {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Basic' + btoa('username:password'),
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    });
```

Can someone explain, what mistake I am making ?

Comment: You're missing a space in the auth header.

Comment: `'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password')`

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Deipirscher : yeah you both are right, thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't have a space after 'Basic'. Change to:

```
 this.data = this.http.get("https://SomeApiCall/api/v1/customers/" , {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'),
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
});
```